# Why visual studio recognizes __asm {} but can't recognize assembly code?

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly

We can use stuff like this in visual studio:

```
__asm
{
    mov   x1,offset thunk_begin; 
    mov   x2,offset thunk_end;
}
```

But as quoted from [here](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Eevans/cs216/guides/vsasm.html):

> Since Visual Studio does not recognize
> assembly code, Visual Studio will have
> to be told what program to call to
> compile the assembly code.

I'm really confused.

Comment: Answer to your only question: "Because it was designed and made that way." Or did you want to ask another question? Because you didn't...

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question.  The link you referred to was talking about stand alone assembler, not assembler embedded in a C source file.  Do you mean "why do we have to tell Visual Studio where the assembler is when assembly embedded in C gets compiled quite happily?"

Comment: Yes,that's what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 6):

That refers to standalone assembly source files, not *inline* asm, which is what your example is.

Comment: Exactly. Poster overlooked that the page talks of .asm files - which are NOT inline Assembler.

Comment: I don't think there are huge difference between .asm and inline Assembler,do you?

Comment: @wamp: The big difference is that, in Visual C++ inline assembler, you can refer directly to symbols from the surrounding C / C++ code. To do so, you need access to the C / C++ compiler's symbol table -- and that pretty much implies that the compiler needs to assemble the inline assembly.